# how to do POST request via proxy by using module request in node js?

Tags: node.js, proxy, request

how to do POST request via proxy by using module request in node js?
what's wrong in code

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
    url: 'https://someurl.com',
    proxy: "41.78.25.186:3128",
    method : 'POST'
    headers : {
        'accept':'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01'
    }

};
request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(response);
    console.log(body);
});
```